# Overlapping elements involving thead and div

Tags: css, html-table, overlapping

Here's my fiddle showing my existing CSS/html:

http://jsfiddle.net/S8Bne/88/

Here's a screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image]

As you can see, I am trying to get the thead block to display in front of the redShadowBox div. How can I control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.geniusPicks .redBoxShadow {margin-bottom: -30px;}
```

Comment: oh nice...what's the margin from bottom relative to? the tr element?

Comment: No the `margin-bottom` is on the redShadowBox. It's a negative margin so that anything directly below the redShadowBox moves up by 30 pixels.